# Integer tuple to string tuple

Tags: list, scala, tuples

Supposedly I have a list of tuples:

```
tuple1: List[(Int, Int)] = List((0,3), (3,6), (6,12), (12,14), (14,15))
```

How can I change it to:

```
tuple1: List[(String, String)] = List((0,3), (3,6), (6,12), (12,14), (14,15))
```

I tried the below:

```
tuple1.unzip match { case(l1, l2) => (l1.toString, l2.toString)}
res9: (String, String) = (List(0, 3, 6, 12, 14),List(3, 6, 12, 14, 15))

tuple1 map(_.toString)
res5: List[String] = List((0,3), (3,6), (6,12), (12,14), (14,15))
```

Both are not result I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close with your attempt. Just need to combine parts of both.

```
tuple1.map { case(l1, l2) => (l1.toString, l2.toString) }
```

Answer (score 1):

For such a simple case I wouldn't bother, but [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) gives you `map` over tuples, see the [documentation](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#hlist-style-operations-on-standard-scala-tuples) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for a `for-yield` if you prefer.

```
for{
  t <- tuple1
} yield (t._1.toString, t._2.toString)
res0: List[(String, String)] = List((0,3), (3,6), (6,12), (12,14), (14,15))
```